# Making a list in user-defined functions

Tags: python, list, function, attributes

I'm trying to understand this error of:

```
  float object has no attribute a
```

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
    def Apple():
             a = input("first: ")
             b = input("second: ")

             list1 = [0..a];
             list2 = [0..b];

             print list1, list2
```

Here is how the error is given

```
    >> Apple()
    >> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Comment: Not sure if this was introduced in posting the question or part of your actual code, but your second `input` has a typo

Comment: What are you looking to do? If you're looking to produce ranges, then that's not how it's done in Python.

Comment: Basically. I've been trying ways to make lists out of parameters inputted by the user, and doing things with numpy to those lists. and then printing the results. But, I just can't seem to make the lists. 


Where is the error, Stephen?

Comment: @NilesBernoulli What gave you the idea that `[0..a]` would make a list?

Comment: @NilesBernoulli I was just pointing out that one of your `input`s was an `inout`. It has since been changed. Joran and Apero seem to have an idea what the overarching issue is.

Comment: When python sees `0..a`, it creates a float (`0.`) and then tries to read an attribute a (`.a`). Its the same thing as `(0.).a`. This has never worked as a range statement in python.

Comment: Although with some `ctypes` hackery, you might be able to override `float.__getattr__('var')` (invoked by `1..var`) to look up `var` in the enclosing frame and return the correct range...

Answer (score 4):

Since the poster asked about the error specifically:

I believe that in the line `list1 = [0..a];`

the python interpreter takes the expression `0..a`, and parses it as the float `0.` followed by a call to the `a` attribute of `0.`, which is usually what a dot means in that context.

As has been mentioned already, to create a range, use `range(0, int(a))` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`range(int(a))` is what you want I think, not `[0..a]`

on a side note input is very dangerous in py2x since it evaluates the input

Comment: not in python ... that is the notation in some other languages though

Comment: good catch ...  (I assume he is using py2 which is why it worked)

Comment: In Python 3, you need to call `list(...)` too, since this would return a generator. :)

Comment: depending on if a generator will work for his needs ... a generator is often perferred (maybe I should have used `xrange`) .. but its moot since I am fairly confident he is using 2x

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean:

```
list1 = range(a)
list2 = range(b)
```

And why these ";" this is **python**, not javascript.